# How to load resources outside of classpath?

Tags: java, spring, resources

I'm using spring framework in webapplication and I would like to load resources (*.jpeg) stored outside of classpath.

I'm calling `GET` method of some controller. It works when I call the photo from classpath. But when I call paths like:
`/ext/media/photos/photo.png`, `file:/ext/media/photos/photo.png`, `/home/user/ext/media/photos/photo.png`, `http://some-web-image`, it doesn't work.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loadPhoto", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> loadPhoto() throws IOException {
    InputStream in = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/ext/media/photos/photo.png");
    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(IOUtils.toByteArray(in), HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

I tried to map url to real location in spring context

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/ext/media/photos/**" location="file:/home/user/ext/media/photos/"/>
```

But I still can't get the resource. Is this right way how to get resource outside of classpath?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [`FileSystemResource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/). You don't need to return a `byte[]`. Spring has a converter for producing the `byte[]` itself.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loadPhoto", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource> loadPhoto() throws IOException {
    FileSystemResource res = new FileSystemResource("/ext/media/photos/photo.png");
    return new ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource>(res, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Comment: @misco I think there's a solution with `mvc:resources` as well and it's probably more efficient with its caching mechanism. I'll see if I can test it later and edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks, it will be fine to know why the solution with `mvc:resources` doesn't work.

Comment: @misco So I ended up trying with `<mvc:resources ... />` and it worked fine for me. You'll have to give more details if you want to figure out why it didn't work for you. Consider asking a new question.